# Android Emulator, cover screen with palm to dim

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to start the android emulator from eclipse. I chose the Nexus7 as my device.  Everything seems to loads fine.  The phone then goes through the steps as if it were an new installation and asks me to cover the screen with my palm to dim the screen.  How do I simulate covering the screen with my palm since I can not get past this step?

I just downloaded eclipse with android bundle so I have the most recent version of everything.

Comment: Could you provide the exact Nexus 7 settings you used to achieve this? I'm not getting the "new installation steps" when trying to recreate the situation.

Comment: I use hose from genymotion, fast and never had that issue.

Comment: I dont think you need to cover the screen, is there some way button to move on to the next step ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your target in AVD.

May be you select your target as Android 4.4W.

W means wearable.

Try to change that target to 4.4.2 or any other target.